# IE8 bug - elements not shown on page until refresh

Tags: internet-explorer-8

Im experiencing a very weird bug in IE8. A bunch of elements arn't shown on the page although with the developer tools I can see they are in the html and arn't being hidden with CSS. Refreshing the page fixes this.

This site is on a local environment and I cant put it online. Ive never heard of a bug like this so does anyone have any ideas for things to look into? Thanks

Comment: Its not IE doing some weird caching thing? try emptying the cache.

Comment: Remove all css and systematically add sections back in until the behaviour presents again? It's probably either awkward css, malformed html, an unpredictable javascript library or all of the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id forgotten to validate the code. I hadnt realised (due to lots of whitespace) but some divs were placed before the opening doctype was specified. Hopefully fixing this will make the issue go away. Thanks

Comment: Wow. First time I forgot to use doctype. It just wasn't present in servlet's template. And I got this problem with IE8. Thanks for your post.